# How do I size and sapce

Tags: sql

```````py
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
``````python
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
``````python
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```````

this is what i needed and i appreciate it guys

Comment: First make sure you understand the process of creating that pyramid, as in: if it was a recipe how would you do it step by step? It's easy for us because we immediately think in a geometric manner, but you can't easily program in those terms. Try to draw it on paper and understand your process first before trying to hammer it in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problems like these, try to associate the output with its indices (or in this case, `current_row`). Also, it seems like it's better to start from 0 for this one.

```
0:                                   1
1:                           2       *       3
2:                   4       *       *       *       5
3:           6       *       *       *       *       *       7
4:   8       *       *       *       *       *       *       *       9
```

`max_row` is 5, `current_row` is from 0 to 4.
There are `max_row - current_row - 1` spaces on each row.
There are `2 * current_row - 1` stars on each row.
The numbers on the left is just twice `current_row`, or `2 * current_row`. This is true for all except 0. We could use an if statement for that special case.
The numbers on the right is just `left + 1`, or `2 * current_row + 1`.

```
space = '\t'
star = '*'
size = int(input("Enter number to make triangle: "))

def printRow(current_row, max_row) :
    star_count = 2 * current_row - 1

    line = space * (max_row - current_row - 1)

    if current_row == 0 :
        line += "1"
    else :
        line += str(2 * current_row) + space

    line += (star + space) * star_count

    if current_row > 0 :
        line += str(2 * current_row + 1)

    print(line)

if size <= 0 :
    print("The value you entered is too small to display a triangle")

for i in range(0, size) :
    printRow(i, size)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to learn how to print python pyramid you can learn it from
[This link](https://pynative.com/print-pattern-python-examples/) , Then try to understand it after you can understand below code

```
space = '\t'
star = '*'

size = int(input("Enter number to make triangle: \n"))

def printRow(current_row, max_row) :
    rPri = 0
    lefNum = 0
    star_count = 2*current_row - 3
    if current_row == 1:
      lefNum = 1
    if current_row > 1:
      lefNum = (current_row-1)*2
      rPri = 1
    rigNum = lefNum + 1
    line = space * (max_row - current_row) + str(lefNum) +  (space + star) * star_count + (space + str(rigNum))*rPri
    print(line)

if size<=0 :
    print("The value you entered is too small to display a triangle")

for i in range(1, size+1) :
    printRow(i, size)
```